# How to make a loop in Python which creates multiple empty lists?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I want a line of code which will create an empty list whose name is determined by an incrementing variable.

Everywhere I've looked thus far has been unhelpful. They suggest instead something which makes a list of empty lists or using a dictionary. This is not what I want, I want a line (or several) of code which just creates an empty list (which is not part of a dictionary or a list of lists, a stand alone entity). I want these lists to be distinct, distinguished by a variable which increments by 1 every time a new empty list is created.

These empty lists can't be made in one batch at the very beginning as I intend to make and delete these lists throughout a recursive function. I need to make multiple lists as my intention is for this function to descend to a new level of recursion but return later to the previous list. These are acting as temporary working lists which calculate a value for each item of an original list and then copy the result into a final list once it is found.

```
str("list_" + i) = []
```

If i = 1, then I would like this line of code to create an empty list with the name "list_1" which I can proceed to interact with throughout my script.

Instead I'm met with `"SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"`

By all means let me know if I'm not making any sense at all and I will do my best to convey my request.

Comment: You know that there's a reason that people are suggesting anything other than what you want? You want a variable number of variables (which is the dupe for this) and it just creates horrible code that can't be followed properly.

Comment: honestly a `defaultdict(list)` sounds ideal even though you say it is not

Comment: while this approach is probably technically possibly, i would advise against it. there are far easier ways to get a list of lists

Comment: I'll assume that you're a new Python developer, in which case, welcome! It sounds like what you want is inconvenient to manage though. I'm not convinced it's a good idea, and would heavily suggest using dictionaries for this purpose

Comment: Are you sure that your recursive algorithm can't work just with lists in local variables? If you do something like `local_list = []` in the body of the function, that will create a separate empty list each time the function is called. It won't share the list with the other calls, either earlier or later, unless you write code to make it do so. Dealing with local variables is *much* nicer than using globals.

Comment: That might work, I honestly have no idea what I'm doing though, thanks for your time it was probably wasted

Comment: Feel free to ask a (separate) question about your real problem. This question sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're asking about some issue with your *solution* to your real problem, and there's a better approach to solving that real problem that doesn't run into this issue. And don't feel bad about getting stuff wrong while you're learning! You'll figure it all out eventually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly advise against this but this achieves what you want depending on your use case:

```
globals()['list_' + str(i)] = []

for i in range(5):
    globals()['list_' + str(i)] = []

list_1
[]

list_2
[]

etc...
```

Depending on your use case switch `globals` for `locals` and vice-versa.

A better idea would be `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_lists = defaultdict(list)
```

Now you don't have to initialize any list until you use it and every key comes with it's value being a `list` already. For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    my_lists['list_' + str(i)].append('foo')

my_lists

defaultdict(list,
            {'list_0': ['foo'],
             'list_1': ['foo'],
             'list_2': ['foo'],
             'list_3': ['foo'],
             'list_4': ['foo']})
```

Comment: This is the least Pythonic, correct answer to a Python question I've ever seen. Strongly suggest the `defaultdict` solution!

Comment: pretty sure the code shows you exactly how to do that in a loop

Comment: Yeah I'm dumb don't worry sorry for asking a stupid question

Comment: In my opinion, the `globals` solution should be removed or demoted to a comment. Really, `defaultdict` is the only recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice but anyway:

```
for i in range(10):       # for global vars
    globals()["list_" + str(i)] = []
print(list_0) # []
```

Maybe what you're looking for is a dictionary:

```
items = dict()
for i in range(10):       # for dictionary 
    items[str("list_" + i)] = []
print(items.list_0) # []
```

Comment: This is incorrect in several ways. `item[str("list_" + i)] = []` but `item` doesn't exist, that's a typo, and I don't understand the point of `MyClass` because it's not even properly defined

Comment: 1. How to set global attributes 2. How to set object properties 3. why you might want to use a dictionary.

Comment: Of course don't use the object if you don't have an object, maybe I should have made that clearer

Comment: Ok, and how does completely invalid code do any of those? This just throws errors.

Comment: This was misleading and I removed it completely, thanks for the feedback

Comment: The error you encountered comes from the question "str("list_" + i)" which is not valid python

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `globals`, use `defaultdict`

Using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is both efficient *and* manageable. You don't need to add keys explicitly when appending to list values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
dd['list_0'].append('foo')

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'list_0': ['foo']})
```

If you want to *explicitly* add keys, even with empty list values, you can do so by feeding an extra argument:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list, **{k: [] for k in [f'list_{i}' for i in range(5)]})

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'list_0': [], 'list_1': [], 'list_2': [],
#                              'list_3': [], 'list_4': []})
```