# Create new list based on 'for' loop variable

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How can I create  as many empty lists as a `for` loop variable determines ?

As in:

```
for i in range(3):
    list_{i} = []  #this is just an idea
```

In the end of the `for` loop I'd have:

```
list_0 = [] #empty, I could add elements later.
list_1 = [] #empty
list_2 = [] #empty
```

I'm new to Python so please if this question is a duplicate, let me know but I haven't found any question with the same needs.

Comment: You cannot do it that way where you end up having variables named list_0, list_1 etc. Seems like a bunch of people have replied with other alternatives that you can use instead :)

Comment: It's a shame nobody's mentioned `collections.defaultdict`. There's a high chance [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54393989/9209546) you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(3): 
    globals()[f'list_{i}'] = []  # Only Python3.6 or higher
```

for python lower than 3.6:

```
for i in range(3): 
    globals()['list_{}'.format(i)] = []
```

then you will have `list_0`, `list_1` and `list_2` equals to `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
lists_= [[] for i in range(3)]
print(lists_)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[], [], []]
```

and then if you want to add elements to a specific list_:

```
lists_[0].append(1)
lists_[0].append(2)
lists_[0].append(3)

print(lists_[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

**EDIT:**

Since OP mentioned that `range` is conditional:

```
cond_1 = False
if cond_1:
    x = 3
else:
    x = 2
lists_= [[] for i in range(x)]
print(lists_)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[], []]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The problem is that the number of lists is unknown, so I need to create a list based on an `if`condition, so I can't tell what's the range.

Comment: @L'recherche. whats the condition, the range can be changed accordingly as well.

Comment: I have a 2d array with 100 rows and 3 columns, so I check:  `if array[i][0] == 1 than create list`, than `i` is incremented, what means that `i`is checking all the 100 rows. In the end if I have 20 rows with the first element equal to 1 (array[i][0] == 1), I'd need 20 lists.

Comment: @L'recherche. kindly check the edit I already made.

Answer (score 1):

**1. You can create a list of a lists the next way using for loop**

```
>>> pool = []
>>> for i in range(3):
>>>    pool.append([])
```

**2. You can create it dynmicly**

```
>>> pool = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

**3. However if you want specify names, maby it is better to store them in a dict**

```
>>> pool = dict([(i, []) for i in range(3)])
```

The output will be:

```
>>> pool
{0: [], 1: [], 2: []}
```

**4. The same example with the readable names**

```
>>> pool = dict([(i, []) for i in ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']])
```

The output in that example will be:

```
>>> pool
{'list1': [], 'list3': [], 'list2': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either via a list comprehension:

```
lst = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

Or via `.append()`:

```
lst = list()
for i in range(3):
    lst.append([])

print(lst)
```